# Evaluate $\int \frac{x^2}{x^2 -6x + 10}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate $$\int \frac{x^2}{x^2 -6x + 10} \, dx$$

I'd love to get a hint how to get rid of that nominator, or make it somehow simpler.

Before posting this, I've looked into: [Solve integral $\int{\frac{x^2 + 4}{x^2 + 6x +10}dx}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1594342/solve-integral-int-fracx2-4x2-6x-10dx)

And I've not understood how they simplied the nominator. I know that it has to match $2x-6$ somehow. but the way they put $(x-6)$ and multipled the integral and have suddenly in the nominator $x+1$ does not make sense to me.

Comment: You can add and subtract $-6x + 10$ in the numerator

Comment: I'm starting by re-writing the nominator as: $x^2 - 6x + 6x$, first integral is trivial. and now i'm working on the second one. hope that makes sense.

Comment: Numerator not [nominator](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nominate).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint : $$\int\frac{x^2}{x^2-6x+10}dx=\int1+\frac{6x-10}{x^2-6x+10}dx$$

$\dfrac{d}{dx} \ln{(x^2-6x+10)}=\frac{2x-6}{x^2-6x+10}$ , therefore make 
$$\frac{6x-10}{x^2-6x+10}=\frac{3(2x-6)}{x^2-6x+10}+\frac{8}{x^2-6x+10}=3\frac{2x-6}{x^2-6x+10}+8\frac{1}{(x-3)^2+1}$$

$$I=x+3\ln(x^2-6x+10)+8\arctan{(x-3)}+constant$$

Comment: That's awesome Steve! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

$$\frac{x^2}{x^2-6x+10}=1+\frac{6x-10}{x^2-6x+10}$$

Now, Partial Fractions.

Comment: Oh now I see, so you took denominator and divided it by nominator. thanks. and the rest I just did partial fractions as you said